# Pass set of functions as arguments to another function in Python

Tags: python

I would like to implement my own basic Runge-Kutta 4 integrator in Python. The format should be something like this:

```
---- EXAMPLE set of equations ----
f1 = lambda x: x**2
f2 = lambda y: y**2
.
.
.
fn = lambda n: n**2
f = [f1, f2, f3, ... , fn]

result = integrate(f, other arguments [e.g. stepsize etc.])

---- result should be of format ----
result = [result1 result2 result3 ... resultn]
```

So basically I want to be able to define, for example, a set of three equations of motion, and be able to pass these to a function and access them to manipulate these equations inside of that function. How is that possible?

Ideally, I want to achive something similar to Matlabs ode45 function, which can be called for example as follows:

```
% ---- file 1 ---- %
function xp=F(t,x)
xp=zeros(2,1);
xp(1)=x(2);
xp(2)=-t*x(1)+exp(t)*x(2)+3*sin(2*t); 

% ---- file 2 ---- %
[t,x]=ode45(’file 1’,[t0,tf],[x10,x20]);

% where t0 tf initial and final values of t
% x10 x20 initial values of x
```

Note 1:
I have already looked at the source for dopri5 in SciPy but it is implemented in C and far too advanced for my purposes.

Note 2:
Let me know if what I've written above is not clear at all, which

Comment: FYI you know this will probably be slow, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: Python isn't designed for writing this sort of low-level numeric stuff. It's certainly good at *managing* it -- `numpy` is a module specifically for handling large numeric datasets and doing calculations like this on them -- but the actual number-crunching is done in low-level C or Fortran for speed. Writing your own integrator is an interesting learning exercise, but it won't teach you that much about how Python is used normally. That said:

---

You can do exactly what you asked for.

```
>>> def integrate(fs):
...     print fs[0](1)
... 
>>> f1 = lambda x: x**2
>>> f2 = lambda x: x**3
>>> 
>>> fs = (f1, f2)
>>> 
>>> integrate(fs)
1
```

This makes sense, because [functions are first-class objects in Python](http://blog.benchside.com/2010/02/treating-python-functions-as-first-class-objects/).

Comment: Awesome, this works indeed. Thanks! I was aware of the fact that Python isn't made for such tasks, but as an exercise it will do. After prototyping it I might still outsource the routine. Thanks again!